# How to determine the Rds(on) from a MOSFET datasheet

Tags: mosfet, rdson

I want to know the R<sub>DS(on)</sub> of this [MOSFET](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c4/6b/5e/57/f4/a8/4d/96/CD00000232.pdf/files/CD00000232.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000232.pdf) when V<sub>GS</sub> = 3.5 V, and I<sub>D</sub> = 5 A .

As you can see, the graph stops at 2.5 A.

[image]
data sheet link:
https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/555356/STMICROELECTRONICS/VNP20N07FI.html

Comment: Some might think it rude not to incorporate a data sheet link to the actual data sheet that you extracted the picture from. Others may say that for each picture you embed, a citation is needed and, a data sheet link suffices for that purpose. Others may not care.

Comment: 1) add a link to the datasheet 2) *As you can see, the graph stops at 2.5 A.* No, the graph stops at 3 A that's still not 5 A so we do not know what \$R_{DS,on}\$ will be at 5 A.

Comment: Extrapolate from existing data? Ask the manufacturer?

Comment: Measure it yourself (that is a challenge if you're new to that) or just use a MOSFET for which \$R_{DS,on}\$ is defined at \$V_{GS}\$ = 3.5 V and \$I_D\$ = 5 A. Also some figures are given at 10 A, from that a designer can deduce if that will be good enough at 5 A. My point: even though that specific \$R_{DS,on}\$ value is not given, from the datasheet it can be determined if this device can do the job. Realize that a lower \$R_{DS,on}\$ is usually OK. If you're relying on a specific \$R_{DS,on}\$ value, you're not designing it properly (\$R_{DS,on}\$ has an unpredicatble value).

Comment: sorry for not adding link to the datasheet , its fixed now. i did mesure the RSON of the mosfet but i want to compare it to the datasheet to know if the mosfet is within the specs or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to know the RDS(on) of this MOSFET when VGS = 3.5 V, and ID = 5
> A*

Try this graph: -

[image]

My estimate of a typical \$R_{DS}\$ is 0.4 volts / 5 amps = 80 mΩ. The true spread of values for a large sample could be anywhere from 40 mΩ to over 160 mΩ with a \$V_{GS}\$ of only 3.5 volts.

It's very approximate (and no matter how you try with MOSFETs, they are not that predictable so if you expect precise definitive values then you will be disappointed).

Comment: thanks man  , this is more than enough for me . i didnt thought of using this graph like that. good think i asked , now i learned a new thing

Comment: @haithem Keep in mind also that this estimate is only valid for drain-to-source voltages around 0.4V. Allowing Vds to increase just a few hundred millivolts will cause dramatic changes in Rds.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the op asked for the RDS at 5 amps so, I expect he can see from the graph above that if the 5 amps changed to (say) 10 amps, VDS would become about 1.6 volts and, RDS would change to 160 milli ohm. (Just saying). It's all a bit hit and miss at this level of detail on MOSFETs.

Comment: But we can't know the actual value of VDS for the OP unless we see the OP's circuit. If the OP doesn't keep VDS well below the overdrive voltage then they will be in the parabolic or saturated part of the curves. I liked your answer, I just wanted to OP to be aware of the constraints.

Comment: thank you for the explainations , as i said i only needed the caracteristics at exactly VGS = 3.5 V, and ID = 5 A  since that is how my circuit works . but i will take notes of your commets for the future projects . thanks again for your time